# How set psql --variable from local .json file in one command?

Tags: psql

My PostgreSQL table has these columns...

```
                                                 Table "public.page_objects"
       Column       |           Type           | Collation | Nullable |                       Default                        
--------------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+------------------------------------------------------
 id_page_object     | integer                  |           | not null | nextval('page_objects_id_page_object_seq'::regclass)
 timestamp_creation | timestamp with time zone |           |          | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
 obj                | jsonb                    |           |          | 
 draft              | boolean                  |           |          | 
 notes              | text                     |           |          |
```

To run a full test of my web app all records need to be deleted and a new record added with a clean json object.  From the psql client, these steps have worked consistently when entered manually....

```
$ DELETE from page_objects;
$ \set data `cat ~/Desktop/import_240109.json`
$ INSERT INTO page_objects (obj) VALUES (:'data');
```

Now I'm trying to set up automated testing (with Cypress, not that it probably matters) and am trying to replicate these manual steps in a single command.  After getting this to work from the command line, the plan is to use it in a bash shell script.  I'm stuck with trying to get a psql command to work with the .json data file on my local drive.  The following seems to be reading the file, but keeps throwing an error...

```
$ psql -c "\c my_database" -c "--variable data=`cat '/Users/patrickreagan/Desktop/import_240123.json'`"
```

The error...

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ""1""
```

The file contains just the app's (big) json object not an entire record. The ""1"" is the first key encountered. For the web app testing data the other columns are either auto-entered, or not needed for the database reset.

What do I need to change? Or is there an entirely different way that's easier?